# Int main inside a class

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point

Simple question, how can I run a program having main inside a class?
I have a code:

MojSwiat2.cpp:

```
int Main::main() {
    // code 
    return 0;
}
```

And MojSwiat2.h:

```
class Main {
public:
    int main();
};
Main run;
int Main::main() { // with this I have error: function int Main::main(void) already has a body
    run.main();
} // and without I got unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
```

Reason I need to do this: [Accessing protected members of class from main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231789/accessing-protected-members-of-class-from-main/23231873?noredirect=1#comment35544236_23231873)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining a normal `main` that only contains a call to your other function. Like this:

```
int main(int, char**) {
    return Main().main();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Could you explain me what (int, char**) does and why it's needed? Is this for console usage? I mean, running from terminal?

Comment: They are parameters without names. This tells the compiler that there will be two parameters of type `int` and `char**`, but you will never use them. You may be more used to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` which is exactly the same, just that the compiler may give a warning since neither `argc` nor `argv` are ever used.

Comment: Thanks for brief explanation :)

Comment: `int main() { /* ... */ }` is also a valid and portable definition for `main`; there's no need to define anonymous parameters.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, I just chose this version because I usually end up using the parameters anyway ;)

Comment: @dionadar: Which is pretty hard to do if they're anonymous. 8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson But it does not change the interface and any forward definitions are still valid

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Main m;
    return m.main();
}
```

or if Main::main is declared static

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return Main::main();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define `main`.

```
class my_app {
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
      // ...
   }
}

my_app app;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return app.main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Optionally the compiler might allow you to set the entry point, but this is non portable and non standard.